# 1.5 - Menu item param 'show_categories' is always empty string

Tags: joomla-1.5

I have menu item with articles preview in section type. In primary parameters there is param like 'show categories'. I choose 'hide' what has value of 0. In view I'm debugging this param by `var_dump($this->params->get('show_categories'));` and... it's empty string! Even when I choose 'show' with value 1 it is still empty. Moreover I tried to change this value in database directly. In #__menus is field "params" and there is a line `show_categories=0`. Strange. Then I've done a small test. In administration panel I changed param value to "show" (value 1) and this change apperars in database, not there is `show_categories=1`. But var_dump still shows empty string...

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I changed menu item type to category preview and then back to section preview, now is ok. Strange but works...